# Is it possible to set two or more types(Integre or float) for 1 field by setting codition in Odoo 9?

Tags: python, file-type, odoo-9

I am try to learn how to customize the odoo system to sovle specific problem in business. I am using  odoo9.0. 
Could we set two types of value(integre and float) for a file by setting the specific conditions for each of them? if it is possible, please teach me ththe right steps to follow. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

In Odoo it's not possible to set two data-type for single field.
But you can create 2 fields Integer and Float and show/hide by setting condition in view.

.py file

```
is_integer = fields.Boolean('Is Integer?')
integer_field = fields.Integer('Integer Field')
float_field = fields.Float('Float Field')
```

.xml file

```
<field name="is_integer" invisible="1" />
<field name="integer_field" attrs="{'invisible': [('is_intiger', '==', False)]}"/>   
<field name="float_field" attrs="{'invisible': [('is_intiger', '==', True)]}"/>
```

Comment: Thank for replying. Have a nice day